# can command line utilities be faster than C++?

Tags: c++, bash, sed, grep

I have a project where I want to manipulate certain output files.

This can be accomplished using a combination of grep and sed and piping with |

Alternatively, I can also write a C++ program to do the same thing.

Is there a conclusive answer on which method will be faster since grep and sed should already be fairly well optimised?

Comment: By the time you wrote the C++ app, the script will be finished a thousand times I think.

Comment: It's considerably difficult write a faster sed/awk/grep etc.

Comment: ...not everything is a nail... know when to use the right tool for the job at hand....

Comment: Alternatively, if the tools end up being too slow (e.g. if you have hundreds of files and are spawning tons of processes), you might be able to get something very fast done with Perl. I'd wager that you could not do better than a Perl script to any level of statistical significance for your purpose!

Answer (score 7):

From a technical standpoint, a well-written self-contained C++ program that does everything you need will be faster than using two (or more) shell commands interconnected with a pipe, simply because there will be no IPC overhead, and they can be tailor-made and optimized for your exact needs.

But unless you're writing a program that will be run 24/7 for years, you'll never notice enough gain to be worth the effort.

And the standard rules for pre-optimization apply...

Comment: And that's even assuming that you know all the algorithms and optimization tricks the developers of grep and sed used

Comment: @KillianDS: I doubt regular expressions in Perl, Python or Boost are any much slower than grep.  For processing a simple file line-by-line, I get much better performance using Python than bash & sed.

Answer (score 4):

If I were you, use what is **already out there** as these have likely been around a long time and have been tested and tried.  Writing a new program yourself to do the same thing seems like a *reinventing the wheel* type action and is prone to error.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need faster performance than you'll get with piping, you can download the source for grep and sed and tailor it to your needs in one application (be wary of licenses if you plan on distributing your code).  I'd be highly surprised if you'd even notice the overhead of piping (like Flimzy mentioned), so if things are really that slow I'd start profiling your app.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that if you are a *very* good C/C++ programmer and spend a *lot* of time, that you will be able to write a program that's faster than the pipeline you're thinking of.  But unless performance is so critical in this case that you absolutely must do it this way you should use the pipeline.